# How to properly handle axios API errors in createasyncthunk

Tags: typescript, axios, react-redux, redux-toolkit

What I would like to achieve is to have a global error handler for my API calls when using react-redux. I would like it redirect to a 404 page when a 404 status code is thrown, or a maintenance page when the backend is not running. Doing this for *every* API call is tedious and having a global error handler that can take care of that would limit repetitive code.

My current setup is as follows:

```
fetchDataReducer.ts
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk<
  string,
  void,
  {
    rejectValue: ErrorResponse;
  }
>('test/fetchData', async (_, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const response = await AxiosApiInstance({
      url: '/fetchData',
      method: 'GET'
    });

    return response.axiosApiResponse?.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error as ErrorResponse);
  }
});

const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(data.pending, (state) => {
        state.data = null;
        state.loading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(data.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.data = action.payload;
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(data.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.data = null;
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload ?? null;
      });
  }
});
```

```
dashboard.component.tsx
export const Dashboard = (): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const {
    data: data,
    loading: loading,
    error: error
  } = useAppSelector((state) => state.dataSlice);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData());
  },[]);

  if (error && error.code) {
   switch(error.code) {
    case '404': 
     return <NotFound />;
    case AxiosError.ERR_NETWORK:
     return <Maintenance />;
    case 'consent_required':
     return <Consent />;
    default: 
     break;
   }
  }

  return (
    {loading === true && <CircularStatic />}
    {error && <Alert severity='error'>{error.message}</Alert>}
    {data != null && (
       <Card sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <CardContent>
          <Grid container spacing={3} sx={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography color='textSecondary' gutterBottom variant='overline'>
                TOTAL {entity}
              </Typography>
              <Typography color='textPrimary' variant='h4'>
                {data.total}
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Avatar
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: 'success.main',
                  height: 56,
                  width: 56
                }}
              >
                {cardIcon}
              </Avatar>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Box
            sx={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              display: 'flex',
              pt: 2
            }}
          >
            {data.total > 0 &&
              data.percentage > 0 &&
              (data.isUpwardArrowDirection ? (
                <ArrowUpwardIcon color='success' />
              ) : (
                <ArrowDownwardIcon color='error' />
              ))}
            {data.percentage === 0 && <HorizontalRule />}
            <Typography
              variant='body2'
              sx={{
                mr: 1
              }}
            >
              {data.percentage} %
            </Typography>
            <Typography color='textSecondary' variant='caption'>
              Since last month
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    )}
  );
};
```

At this point I have the error saved in the state but if I have multiple API calls I don't want to be go through each API response and check the error, I'd like to have a global error handler that can do that and redirect to 404 or maintenance page if necessary. This would not work in the reducer, it has to be the component to be able to redirect to a different url. Please any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I added the component to show where I am checking for the status code and showing the relevant content based on status code. For multiple API calls that would be messy *really* fast! Ideally having a central place to handle these errors would be best and I can't wrap my head around how to do that with redux. Without redux I had an ErrorHandler HOC sitting above my components that accepted the error object and handled the error. With redux I'm unable to use a hook when I execute the API call which is where I could pass in the error. Hope this clarifies more and thank you for the suggestions.

```
ErrorHandler.compontent.tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { type ErrorResponse } from '@lib/errorResponse.type';
import {
  createContext,
  type Dispatch,
  type FC,
  type SetStateAction,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useState
} from 'react';
import { AxiosErrors } from '@lib/helpers';
import { Maintenance } from '@components/maintenance';
import SignIn from '@pages/login';
import { errorMessage } from './notifications/baseNotifications';
import { NotFound } from './notFound';

interface ErrorHandlerProps {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
const ErrorStatusContext = createContext<Dispatch<SetStateAction<ErrorResponse | null>> | null>(
  null
);

export const ErrorHandler: FC<ErrorHandlerProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [errorResponse, setErrorResponse] = useState<ErrorResponse | null>(null);

  const renderContent = (): JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element | undefined => {
    const errorStatusCode = errorResponse?.code;
    const message = errorResponse?.message;
    const name = errorResponse?.name;

    if (message != null && name != null) {
      errorMessage(message, name);
    }

    switch (errorStatusCode) {
      case 'consent_required':
        <Consent />;
      case 'Login required':
        return <SignIn />;
      case AxiosErrors.ERR_NETWORK:
        return <Maintenance />;
      case '404':
        return <NotFound />;
      default:
        return children;
    }
  };

  const contextPayload = useMemo(() => setErrorResponse, [setErrorResponse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStart = (url: string): void => {
      setErrorResponse(null);
    };

    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleStart);
    };
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <ErrorStatusContext.Provider value={contextPayload}>
      {renderContent()}
    </ErrorStatusContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useErrorResponse = (): Dispatch<SetStateAction<ErrorResponse | null>> | null =>
  useContext<Dispatch<SetStateAction<ErrorResponse | null>> | null>(ErrorStatusContext);
```

EDIT:
Tried implementing Fer Toasted suggestion but getting type error. Same one as shown in this playground: Getting type error in the createCustomAsyncThunk, same error when looking at this playground -> [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoIIGcCeAdkgCoAWAroQNYA0eRplNACuvgDYToAmAwmkzR6BYuSrUAvnABmUCCDgByAAJoeFAB4ArXAHoYECB2rAYSgFAXghLFBnokqOOJrYWAST4RCM4AHNESStUTUhYOCQfXHgUDCwAWXwAeQB3QgYxZmo4AF44AB4AJVQYCihCVB5aF2zsKED89EJ8AD4ACgs4OBh8MFQALjgYqBt-Wi6e7KHMpgk2Tm5+QUMoYtLyyuraiXr-VpruuD09QoBaM7gAN1QofDgqXHLnCBkp4Fw4S7J0G57RqpwEDNe4wMhjT5kW6oCwAShmojmNHWZQqVRqrmoewxdU83l8AVaeSJCEmaFRhEiKxwiMxKM26J2bgaON2eJ8fn2nSOPT6qAmPPQiLg7XQLKmbI8sOJiEmPJgd1lPJ5JzgPAgwwUzhiFBkbyhaCmmDgPzA-UInx8cFQN0VjhgwB8cuV5M2cHQqXQZglNFF4rBkthzu60iQmCQZBFtyg0tJyqOqvVmpA2rKepN0KN8FN5stlJtt3u0egwaOroqPqxngAdGhtKgkDAAOpmMgANXQHAoqHahAoHA4QfjwR5kgFcCDwQsUQt8BA+ExeSp8VQSTSGVp2XaACIZEZtzV2tLckTd-ugxZVWCPnAb4Y4AAjZyhfqNxn4CAUNXAHhwQgQeBen6d0Gh6DUAAMrggH9wIsedMSPKwZxiIEF2yAAmJc4kwVcUnSWY6RGMZaCgn8OjPCADxFY9Tz3SiL3gjCjyAA)

Comment: I guess you haven't discovered [axios interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) yet. Can you [edit] the post to share a more related [mcve] where you check for a 404 response status and attempt to redirect to a specific page?

Comment: I added more code and explanation as requested.

Comment: I see, you are waiting for the response error to get all the way back to the UI to unpack and process the status code. I'd recommend taking a look at the interceptors so you can immediately check the response status before axios hands it back off to the app code. Interceptors can be set as an axios global, on an instance, and per request if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a reusable wrapper to catch possible errors

```
import {createAsyncThunk,AsyncThunkPayloadCreator,AsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface ThunkAPIConfig {}

export const createMyOwnAsyncThunk = <Returned, ThunkArg = any>(
  type: string,
  thunk: AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Returned, ThunkArg>, 
): AsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkAPIConfig> => {
  return createAsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkAPIConfig>(
    type,
    async (arg, thunkAPI) => {
      try {
        // do some stuff here that happens on every action
        return await thunk(arg, thunkAPI)
      } catch (err) {
        // do some stuff here that happens on every error
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(null)
      }
    },
  )
}
```

which is implemented this way

```
export const fetchData = createMyOwnAsyncThunk<string, void>(
  'test/fetchData',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await AxiosApiInstance({
      url: '/fetchData',
      method: 'GET',
    });

    return response.axiosApiResponse?.data;
  }
);
```

And to pass your push method it might look something like this

your **store.js** or wherever you declare your `configureStore`

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
export const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];

function initStore(initialState, extraArg) {
   // your configureStore should look something like this
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: true,
    preloadedState: initialState,
    // youll add a getdefaultmiddleware here for the extra arguments
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        thunk: {
          extraArgument: {
            push: extraArg, // this is the router push that will be available in your actions with the thunkAPI object
          },
        },
      }).concat(middlewares),
  });
}


export function useStore(initialState, routerPushExtraArg) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
  const store = useMemo(() => initStore(initialState, routerPushExtraArg), [initialState, routerPushExtraArg]);
  return store;
}
```

The **client** component that you use to wrap with your redux `Provider`

```
// in your component, could be _app.js for nextjs or app.js if using react only or wherever you wrap your app with the provider
const routerPush = useRouter().push;
const store = useStore(_, routerPush);

<Provider store={store}>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Interesting, could I redirect or show 404 or Maintenance page there? I don't think I can do anything component related there can I?

Comment: You would have to pass to pass the method that you use for navigating in the client (probably `router.push` if you are using nextjs) as an extra argument https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#injecting-config-values-into-thunks and that method will be available to be used in the `thunkApi` object, e.g. `thunkApi.push`.

Comment: Interesting, would you by any chance be able to produce a rough draft of what that would look like?

Comment: edited initial post, getting type errors with this implementation. Same error as in the playground link posted